# 2 Channel Relay normal open is not working with NodeMCU but led on board light up

Tags: arduino-ide, esp8266, relay, nodemcu

I am pretty new to NodeMCU (ESP8266) and Arduino IDE in general. I followed various documentation / blogs to set up 2 Channel Relay with NodeMCU chip.

Below is sketch code for it.

```cpp
#include<CayenneMQTTESP8266.h>
#define CAYENNE_DEBUG
#define CAYENNE_PRINT Serial

#define LEFT_GARAGE 4
#define RIGHT_GARAGE 5

char ssid[] = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
char password[] = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

char username[] = ""XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";";
char mqtt_password[] = ""XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";";
char client_id[] = ""XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";";

void setup() {
  Cayenne.begin(username, mqtt_password, client_id, ssid, password);
  pinMode(LEFT_GARAGE, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LEFT_GARAGE, HIGH);
  pinMode(RIGHT_GARAGE, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RIGHT_GARAGE, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  Cayenne.loop();
}

// Left Garage Door
CAYENNE_IN(0){
  int currentValue = getValue.asInt();
  digitalWrite(LEFT_GARAGE,!currentValue);
}

//Right Garage Door
CAYENNE_IN(1){
  digitalWrite(RIGHT_GARAGE,!getValue.asInt());
}
```

On relay board I tried to connect wire in 2 different configuration.

1st Config:

```
vcc -> 3.3v from NodeMCU
in1 -> D1/GPIO 04 from NodeMCU
in2 -> D2/GPIO 5 from NodeMCU
GND -> GRD from NodeMCU
```

2nd Config:

```
vcc -> 5v USB from NodeMCU
in1 -> D1/GPIO 04 from NodeMCU
in2 -> D2/GPIO 5 from NodeMCU
GND -> GRD from NodeMCU
```

In 1st config, On relay board respective LED's are turning on when Cayenne buttons are pressed but when I check for continuity on multi meter I don't get anything.

In 2nd config, no LED and no continuity.

am I missing something here? Any feedback/comments are highly appreciated.
[image: 2 Channel Relay]
[image: NodeMCU Setup]

Answer (score 1):

Your second configuration is right because from picture of relay module it clear that it requires 5V supply.

relay working principal is:

- when the signal port(in1/in2) is at low level, the signal light will light up and the optocoupler (it transforms electrical signals by light and can isolate input and output electrical signals) will conduct, and then the transistor will conduct, the relay coil will be electrified, and the normally open contact of the relay will be closed.
- When the signal port(in1/in2) is at high level, the normally closed contact of the relay will be closed. So you can connect and disconnect the load by controlling the level of the control signal port.

As you mentioned that in second configuration there is no LED glow. For find out solution of your problem, you have do one test. Test voltage level of D1/D2. Just make connection on breadboard as mentioned in image.[image]

If voltage level is correct that it might be problem with your relay module.

Also I have attached here relay connection reference for your directness.[image]